# For loop initial value not correct

Tags: java

In my code I want to initialize my i variable in the for loop the some value as the variable j, but for some reason, when j=5, i will not just get the value from j, and decided to still be 4.

I am so confuse whey the value don't get assigned correctly
Here's my code

```
class Solution {

    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
        {

            if(nums[i]==0)
            {
                moveZerosHelp(nums,i);

            }
        }
    }

    public void moveZerosHelp(int[] nums, int zeroIndex)
    {
        System.out.println("zeroIndex: "+zeroIndex);
        int j =zeroIndex+1;
        System.out.println("J value "+j);
        for(int i=j; i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("I value is "+ i);
            printArray(nums);
            if(nums[i]!=0)
            {
                nums[zeroIndex]=nums[i];
                nums[i]=0;
                moveZerosHelp(nums,i);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution s = new Solution();
        int[] nums = {0,1,0,3,12};
        s.moveZeroes(nums);
    }
    
    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
        for(int num : arr) {
            System.out.print(num+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    
}
```

And here's the output:

```
zeroIndex: 0
J value 1
I value is 1

0 1 0 3 12 

zeroIndex: 1
J value 2
I value is 2

1 0 0 3 12 

I value is 3

1 0 0 3 12 

zeroIndex: 3
J value 4
I value is 4

1 3 0 0 12 

zeroIndex: 4
J value 5
I value is 4

1 3 0 12 0 

I value is 2
1 3 0 12 0 

I value is 3
1 3 0 12 0
```

Comment: Huh?  do not understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `nums.length == 5` in `moveZerosHelp(int[] nums, int zeroIndex)` so `for(int i=j; i<nums.length;i++)` become `for(int i=5; i<5;i++)`, then the loop will not be executed.

Comment: Hi @iamphduc, small correction there. He is asking about the case when j = 5;
So, nums.length = 5 and i = j = zeroIndex + 1 = 5.
You would have to update your answer.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot.

Comment: I figured out the problem yesterday, whenever I call the moveZerosHelp(nums,I); inside the moveZeroHelp(), it should be returned immediately after. That's why when I reaches 5 and stop in the current scope, and return back to the previous scope and i=4. So that's basically how it printed j=5 then right after it print out i=4

Comment: for(int i=j; i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("I value is "+ i);
            printArray(nums);
            if(nums[i]!=0)
            {
                nums[zeroIndex]=nums[i];
                nums[i]=0;
                moveZerosHelp(nums,i);
                return; //this line fixed the bug
            }
        }